# Find the exact word using a regex or hashmap

Tags: java, string

I have the following 2 strings

```java
String source1 = "Samsung Galaxy S10";
String source2 = "Samsung Galaxy S10+";
```

I tried by using pattern and matcher to get the exact value I want, but unfortunately without any success.

What I want to achieve is that, if I am searching for `"Samsung Galaxy S10"`, it will only return to me source 1 without source2.

The opposite that if I am search for `"Samsung Galaxy S10+"`, it will only returns the exact one, in this case is source2.

I want the solution to be more flexible not just for this specific example.

I have the idea as follow, but I don't know how to pass the correct pattern for this case.

```java
private boolean isContain(String source) {
    String pattern = // NO IDEA; maybe something like \b[A-Z]\b I don't know. 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: Regex is not really what you want. You're looking (I think) for 'fuzzy matching'. You can do that with something like `s.toLowerCase().contains("samsung galaxy")`

Comment: Perhaps [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy) is what you're looking for, here?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from your description it sounds like you're looking for an exact match to `source`. Why bother with the regex instead of just utilizing `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,   The situation is that there is a list, contains a lot of different devices.  I am using a post API that passes the device model name I am looking for then returns the exact one. The issue is that, if I am searching "Samsung Galaxy S10" it returns to me "Samsung Galaxy S10+", that's why I was thinking regex maybe help. I can be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a `List` and you are looking for an exact match, you could just use [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)); so no need for using regular expressions.

If you want the match to be case-insensitive, you need to loop over the list and use `String`'s `equalsIgnoreCase` method prior to comparing:

```java
for (String item : list) {
    if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

---

If the list of items is fairly large, then you're probably better off using a `HashSet`. The advantage of using a `HashSet` over a `List` is that a `HashSet` has a lookup time complexity of *O(1)*. So calling [`HashSet::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) returns `true` if the set contains the given value. If you want to match case-insensitive, then make sure you call `toLowerCase()` on the `String` prior to adding it to the `HashSet`.

Note that a `Set` may not contain duplicate elements, but in this case, duplicates are pointless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Begins with ^ and ends with $, gives you exact match.

```
private static boolean isContain(String source) {
        String pattern = "^Samsung Galaxy S10$";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
        return m.find();
}
```